# Selecting to multiple tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to select entries from user input `$query`. I would like to search the `first_name`, `last_name`, `address` (etc) columns that has NULL on `deleted_at`. What I have done so far is:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
      ->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
      ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
      ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%')
          ->whereNull('deleted_at')
          ->get();
```

My goal is to search the above mentioned columns by the user's query and show any match it finds. Problem is, it also shows entries that are NOT NULL in the column `deleted_at`. I wish to only see results which are NULL at `deleted_at.` What may I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping)

```
$data = DB::table('users')
  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
  ->where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
       ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
       ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $query. '%');
   })
  ->get();
```

Comment: I understand, this solves the problem I have. By the way, if I want to add another where AND clause, I just need to add ->where('another_column', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') correct?

Comment: and correct me if I'm not mistaken, should you like add a ";" at the end of the last ->orWhere clause?

Comment: It depends to your use case. You can test the behavior with trial and error (best way to understand how it works) :)

Comment: Just to give some inforation. It worked when I did this: `->where(function($string) use ($query) {
                    $string->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');`
                })